# Как организовать распараллеливание работы исправления конфликтов мерджа в Git?

Tags: git, git-merge

Есть бранч, в нем двумя людьми делалась работа. Достаточно много конфликтных файлов. Можно ли как-то распараллелить задачу исправления конфликтов на двоих людей, чтобы один исправил свои изменения, а другой свои?

Заранее спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерная схема работы:

1. Выполнить merge, но не делать push (хотя это и так не получится);
2. Выявить проблемные файлы и коммиты изменившие их;
3. Распределить между собой коммиты;
4. Сделать `git cherry-pick идентификатор коммита` для группы коммитов и решать проблемы на месте. Можно так же использовать `git cherry-pick --no-commit список коммитов через пробел`.

Такой метод не способствует чистоте в репозитории, зато позволяет постепенно подойти в решению конфликтов.

Answer (score 0):

Садится вместе и мержить. Либо нужно было в двух отдельных ветках вести, либо время от времени нужно вмерживать изменения с мастера.